# netstat: parse (awk?) output to return "Program name" not "PID/Program name"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, netstat

UBUNTU 14.04

`netstat -p` outputs both "PID/Program name" in the same column.  I just want "Program name" in that column.  What's the easiest way to do this?

**Actual Output**

```
root@neo4j1:~# netstat -tlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      1020/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      1020/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:7473               [::]:*                  LISTEN      31380/java
tcp6       0      0 [::]:7474               [::]:*                  LISTEN      31380/java
```

**Desired Output**

```
root@neo4j1:~# netstat -tlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Program name
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:7473               [::]:*                  LISTEN      java
tcp6       0      0 [::]:7474               [::]:*                  LISTEN      java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
netstat -tlp | sed 's,[0-9]\+/,,'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using grouping with Sed:

```
netstat -tlp | sed 's/\(^.*\)\( [0-9]*\/\)\(.*$\)/\1\3/g'
```

Though RTLinuxSW's answer is much cleaner.